# Is int same as integer in SQL?

Tags: sql

In official JDBC tutorial code:

```
String createString =
  "create table COFFEES " + "(COF_NAME varchar(32) NOT NULL, " +
  "SUP_ID int NOT NULL, " + "PRICE numeric(10,2) NOT NULL, " +
  "SALES integer NOT NULL, " + "TOTAL integer NOT NULL, " +
  "PRIMARY KEY (COF_NAME), " +
  "FOREIGN KEY (SUP_ID) REFERENCES SUPPLIERS (SUP_ID))";
```

there are `int` data type and `integer` data type. Are they the same?

Comment: The answer is: Yes.

Comment: @jarlh But I have not found any document about int data type?

Comment: http://www.c4learn.com/java/java-integer-data-type/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from [MYSQL 5.0 online reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html)

The keyword INT is a synonym for INTEGER.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are 100% the same in sql

Answer (score 0):

If you check out [this table](https://db.apache.org/ojb/docu/guides/jdbc-types.html) of Mapping of JDBC Types to Java Types, you'll see that the JDBC type "INTEGER" maps to the Java type "int". There are also other types for different kind of integers.

```
TINYINT  -  byte
SMALLINT -  short
INTEGER  -  int
BIGINT   -  long
```